# What formula is being used to calculate ys in the following code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm not able to understand the formula for predicting the ys to plot the graph.

How can it be `ys = (-theta[0] - theta[1] * xs) / theta[2]`?

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12, 3))
axes = axes.ravel()

for k, theta in enumerate(tha[:3]):
    ax = axes[k]
    xs = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    ys = (-theta[0] - theta[1] * xs) / theta[2]
    ax.plot(xs, ys, lw=0.5)
    dfa.query('label ==  1').plot.scatter(x='x1', y='x2', ax=ax, color='blue')
    dfa.query('label == -1').plot.scatter(x='x1', y='x2', ax=ax, color='red')
```

Comment: Can you please specify where from are your thetas?

Comment: theta_0, theta_1 and theta_2 are the model training parameters.

Comment: I see, can can you provide mor details about the model?

Comment: on this website: https://gtraskas.github.io/post/ex2/  under *Evaluating logistic regression* section, they used the same formula (i.e. plot_y = -(theta[0] + theta[1] * plot_x) / theta[2] ) for the prediction of y. But from where if comes from?

Comment: Give you some explanation in answer with screenshot. Sorry for my english. If needed can provide you some extra links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you don't predict `ys`, in the formula both `xs` and `ys` are your features, so probably better name them `x1` and `x2`.

This formulas both define the same decision boundary:

```
ys = (-theta[0] - theta[1] * xs) / theta[2]
theta[2] * ys = (-theta[0] - theta[1] * xs)
```

But to plot the boundary you should define one feature with other.

So here `ys` are not your predictions your prediction is the sign of 
this expression which depends of two features `xs` and `ys`:

```
 theta[0] + theta[1] * xs + theta[2] * ys
```

on the plot this is line which divide your points in two groups. I attached screenshot from your link where this describes.

[image]